# What does -spec, -type, -opaque means in erlang programming

Tags: erlang

I found that -define is Macro, -record is like C's structure, and -include is used for header.but what does -spec, -type or -opaque means? I tried to search on internet and search in document,didn't find the answer

Comment: http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html